# Remove broken plugin from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have an error during upgrading my Eclipse version Mars, 64bit

[image]

The problem is, I can't really uninstall it because there is no such plugin in installed software:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the plugin manually, the location for the plugin folder is as follows: 
**eclipse->plugins**

inside the plugins directly, search for the speicific plugin folder, delete it and then restart eclipse. Then it should work.